# Elastic Search Update Mapping On The Fly

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, spring-data-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

I would like to create (and later update) an index without knowing which fields it will contain.  Right now I am doing so as follows:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/myIndexName?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "settings" : {
        "index" : {
            "number_of_shards" : 3,
            "number_of_replicas" : 2
        }
    },
    "mappings" : {
        "myIndexName" : {
            "dynamic" : true,
            "numeric_detection": true,
            "properties" : {}
        }
    }
}
'
```

and this works just great.

Now, the story goes as follows.  Many people will come to a web page and enter information, some will be `text`-based and some will be `double`-based.  I add new fields to the index with the correct types, and insert their new documents.  I will not know the field names or types until the users enter them.

The problem is that I am unable to get the correct field types to appear in Elastic Search, which makes it very difficult to search the numeric types.

What I have tried

1. The `numeric_detection` property is doing a crappy job so I am unable to rely on it.
2. I *could* use a `dynamic_template` but that would require me to modify field names and I *strongly* prefer to not do that.
3. I am unable to use the PredefinedTransportClient because of a conflict with transitive dependencies at `org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty3Plugin`.  There is a `Put Mapping` request that can be dispatched with this TransportClient that I would like to dispatch from another client.
4. I am using the RestHighLevel Java Client.  I am currently trying to dispatch a put mapping request using this [tutorial](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/_changing_the_application_8217_s_code.html#java-rest-high-level-migration-manage-indices).  But I am not correctly forming the request, my code looks as follows

   ```
     final Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
     for (String key : esHeaderTypes.keySet()) {
       final Map<String, String> typeMap =
           new HashMap<String, String>() {
             {
               put("type", esHeaderTypes.get(key).name());
             }
           };
       properties.put(key, typeMap);
     }

     final Map<String, Object> propertiesMap = new HashMap<>();
     propertiesMap.put("properties", properties);

     HttpEntity entity =
         new NStringEntity(OBJECT_MAPPER.writeValueAsString(propertiesMap), ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);

     Response response = restHighLevelClient
         .getLowLevelClient()
         .performRequest("PUT", index, Collections.emptyMap(), entity);
     LOGGER.debug("putMapping Response: ", response);
   ```

but this throws an exception, which I will post later when I am able to find it again.

Any advice you could offer would be greatly appreciated.  I am unable to make use of `cURL` command-like code without a little extra help.

I am using

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
      <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
      <version>6.2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
      <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-client</artifactId>
      <version>6.2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
      <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
      <version>6.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```